# "Как зомби" — сравнительный оборот или часть сказуемого?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

**Люди сидят в "Инстаграме" как зомби.**
Нужна ли запятая перед союзом?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна, поскольку "как" в данном случае используется [при сравнении](https://best-language.ru/zapjataja-pered-kak-stavitsja). То есть дело в семантике.

Люди сидят - где? (в Инстаграмме / в Кремле / на зоне).

Люди сидят - как кто? (как страусы / как зомби / как зайчики).

Answer (score 2):

Люди сидят в "Инстаграме" как зомби.

Запятую ставить не надо. *Сидят как зомби*: обстоятельство не входит в сказуемое, но тесно связано с ним по смыслу и дополняет семантику глагола.

**ЗОМБИ**, неизм.; м. [англ. zombie из африкан. zumbi - амулет, талисман]. 1. В поверьях населения Западной Африки и Антильских островов: оживлённый в помощью колдовства мертвец, полностью лишённый человеческих чувств и выполняющий любые приказания своего хозяина. 2. Разг. О человеке, готовом слепо, без рассуждений исполнить волю других людей.

Зомби в обычном представлении - это запрограммированный робот, не управляющий сознательно своими действиями. Поэтому оборот *как зомби* имеет качественное значение и может быть обстоятельством, также  он тесно связан со сказуемым, дополняет его смысл.

Поэтому:

Вар.1.  Люди сидят в "Инстаграме" как зомби. Ударение только на обороте (по аналогии с обстоятельством).

Вар.2 Люди сидят в "Инстаграме" постоянно, как зомби. А здесь у нас получился однородный ряд.

Если вы не согласны, то я приведу примеры:

Работники потихоньку расползаются домой, менеджеры ходят как зомби, с полузакрытыми глазами...

До пяти муж как зомби бродил по квартире, смахнул со стола на пол мою любимую вазочку...

Сыро, холодно, ужас. Поспала, слонялась остаток дня как зомби.

Можно еще переделать наше предложение: Люди в "Инстаграме" сидят // как зомби.

Люди сидят в "Инстаграме" - это незаконченное по смыслу предложение, автор нам ничего не сказал, только начал говорить, а сравнительный оборот - это попутное сравнение, оно не входит в основную речь.

Еще довод: можно сидеть в "Инстаграме" и не быть зомби, то есть находиться там для общения, обмена мнениями, поиска информации и т.д., а это уже вполне осознанное поведение, а не "наркотическая зависимость".

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, это в чистом виде сравнительный оборот, здесь нет значения "в качестве" или "будучи".

Answer (score 0):

По-моему,"как зомби" можно воспринимать и как сравнение, и как обстоятельство. В европейских языках оно входит во фразеологизмы, даже в русском языке есть фразеологизм "ходит как зомби" (почти спит, ничего не понимает),  и "сидит как зомби" тоже может восприниматься как фразеологизм (= на грани жизни и смерти).

Так что запятая тоже зависит от восприятия автора: если он имеет в виду бессознательные действия и только - запятой нет, если весь вид человека ему напоминает зомби - это сравнение и запятая есть.

Comment: Мне кажется, что смысл такой. Люди "подсели" на социальную сеть, они не могут не сидеть там, их неудержимо туда тянет. Может быть,  они и не хотели бы всё время проводить там, но уже не управляют собой. Их будто запрограммировали,  они стали как зомби

Comment: Это понятно, все так понимают, но при этом "сидит как зомби" может восприниматься как фразеологизм "сидит как зомби= в бесчувственном состоянии", а может быть сравнением, если представляем картинку зомби (человек сравнивается с зомби). Сравнивается предмет с предметом, а если относится к глаголу, то это уже не сравнение.